# Why PHP header() is not working?

Tags: php, nginx, mamp

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    echo "test";
?>
```

I use this code and its not working in MAMP and the response headers are:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 15 Mar 2017 15:12:45 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.4
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.1
```

Comment: Did you try returning some valid XML?

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't the A in mamp stand for Apache? Why is this tagged nginx?

Comment: If you will return valid XML then it work, right now it is considering an empty document.

Comment: It's tagged as nginx as the `Server` header in response is `nginx/1.11.4`

Comment: Does your nginx configuration manipulate your headers? Can you please add your configuration here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    echo "<example>hello, world!</example>";
```

Gives you:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Wed, 15 Mar 2017 15:12:45 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.4
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.1
```

Links:

- [Working Example.](http://apps.webniraj.com/xml.php)
- [Source Code.](http://apps.webniraj.com/xml.phps)

Comment: Works 100%. See the working example and source code links. You're doing something wrong.